# Reference one resource from another ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

For example, we have two `ResourceDictionary`:

**Global.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <FontFamily x:Key="GlobalFontFamily">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Part.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ReousrceDictionary Source="Global.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <FontFamily x:Key="PartFontFamily">**Reference GlobalFontFamily here**</FontFamily>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ReousrceDictionary Source="Part.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource PartFontFamily}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In some view, I would use `PartFontFamily` to set the element font family. Which I would like to achieve is, use the specified font family when `PartFontFamily` is set, otherwise use `GlobalFontFamily` instead. So I want to keep the `PartFontFamily` key, and reference it to `GlobalFontFamily` since customers have no specified font family for `PartFontFamily`.

Any good suggestions?

Comment: What was the file your part `ResourceDictionary` is present?

Answer (score 0):

Merge your Part.xaml to the Global.xaml... so that you can refer every thing from the Global.xaml...

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ReousrceDictionary Source="Part.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<FontFamily x:Key="GlobalFontFamily">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
```

Merge the Global.xaml to your MainWindow...

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ReousrceDictionary Source="Global.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock FontFamily="{DynamicResource PartFontFamily}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

You can directly access the `PartFontFamily` here...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that's not the key point. Here access the `PartFontFamily` we can achieve it, we just want to reference `PartFontFamily` to `GlobalFontFamily` in Global.xaml in default.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to make an **`alias`** for your resource.

```
<DynamicResource x:Key="PartFontFamily" ResourceKey="GlobalFontFamily"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I would like to specify `PartFontFamily`? What I want to achieve is some like this: `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SomeBrush" Color="{StaticResource SomeColor}" />`. But `FontFamily` has no such constructor.

Comment: @Jerry - With posted answer, you are declaring `PartFontFamily` only and refering to Font Segoe UI. Have you tried it?

Comment: We gave up the thoughts at last, since `<FontFamily x:Key="PartFontFamily">{{ DynamicResource GlobalFontFamily }}</FontFamily>` syntax is impossible between two ResourceDictionaty. Thanks anyway.